# Retrieve element name

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<Package ID="b7137f2>   
<Compatibility_Rules ID="32fd84b4-7b9b-40e2-8265-8e2e4f856a8d">
    <Rule_Event ID="992f04cb-6bd1-42bb-9578-87793dd38aca">
        <Name>Entity Selection</Name>
    </Rule_Event><Rule_Name>Private Line Exclusions</Rule_Name>
    <Rule_Statement ID="d0cc0700-2199-4a51-af68-72dfe27d878f">
        <Description>Package is Private line</Description>
    </Rule_Statement>
</Compatibility_Rules>
</Package>
</Root>
```

I want to extract the attribute name "Rule Event" and display it as :

```
<attribute depth="0">
        <name>Compatibility Rules</name>
        <value GUID="B7137F2">
            <attributes>
                <attribute depth="1">
                    <name>Rule Event</name>
                    <value GUID="32FD84B4">
                        <attributes/>
                     </value> 
                </attribute>
           </attributes>
          </value>
 </attribute>
```

I tried the following but name() returns the parent of Rule Event i.e Compatibility Rules.

```
  <xsl:template match="Compatibility_Rules"> 
    <attribute depth="0">           
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            </name>
        <value GUID="{../../*/@ID}"></value>
        <attributes>
            <attribute depth="1">
                <name><xsl:value-of select="name()"/> </name>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </attribute>          
</xsl:template>
```

How can I get to Rule Event. I am totally new to XML and XSL.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. First of all, your desired output, as you describe it, is not even well-formed. Could you describe the desired effect in a couple of sentences?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: name(*[1])